# Android Exoplayer Audio Streaming not working

Tags: java, android, url, audio-streaming, exoplayer

```
String url = "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2558";
Uri radioUri = Uri.parse(url);

Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(Player.this, "ExoPlayerDemo");
DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(Player.this, null, userAgent);
ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(
          radioUri, dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE * BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT);
MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);

player.prepare(audioRenderer);
player.sendMessage(audioRenderer,MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_VOLUME, 1f);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

player.release();
```

in this code audio is not playing and and it is giving Skipped 60 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. please give suggestions

Comment: please share working code of audio and video player of exo player

Answer (score 1):

Url "http://www.noiseaddicts.com/free-samples-mp3/?id=2558" is not correct. It's for web page.

don't reales before audio is played.